# Un programa para confirmar o rechazar una contraseña

Tags: python, funciones

El problema es el siguiente, necesito una función de nombre `verificar_clave()` que reciba como argumento una cadena cualquiera que representa una contraseña y devuelva `True` si cumple con todas las medidas de seguridad, y `False` si no cumple con al menos una de esas medidas.

> **Medidas de seguridad:**
>
> - Longitud mínima de seis (6) caracteres
> - Longitud máxima de doce (12) caracteres
> - Contiene al menos una (1) letra mayúscula entre A y Z
> - Contiene al menos dos (2) letras minúsculas entre a y z
> - Contiene al menos de cuatro (4) números entre 0 y 9

Pensando (y un poco de ayuda de internet) ahora tengo esto:

```
def verificar_clave(passw):

    validar=False
    long=len(passw)
    espacio=False
    mayuscula=False
    minuscula=False
    numeros=False
    y=passw.isalnum()
    correcto=True

    for carac in passw:
        if carac.isspace()==True:
            espacio=True
        if carac.isupper()== True:
            mayuscula=True
        if carac.islower()== True:
            minuscula=True
        if carac.isdigit()== True:
            numeros=True

    if espacio==True:
        validar=False
    else:
        validar=True

    if long <=6 or long >=12 and validar==True:
        validar=False

    if mayuscula == True and minuscula ==True and numeros == True and y == False and validar ==True:
       validar = True
    else:
       correcto=False

    if validar == True and correcto==False:
       return False

    if validar == True and correcto ==True:
       return True
```

Pero a la hora de  probar la función me pasan 2 cosas:

```
print verificar_clave('MiClave2016')
#debería obtener: True

print verificar_clave('MiClaveSegura2016')
#debería obtener: False

print verificar_clave('miclave2016')
#debería obtener: False

print verificar_clave('MICLAVE2016')
#debería obtener: False

print verificar_clave('MiClave16')
#debería obtener: False

print verificar_clave('mica')
#debería obtener: False
```

Y únicamente **no se me cumplen el primero y el último**... Se que es por los true y false pero es que ya se me quemó la cabeza y por eso recurro a ustedes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te estas complicando demasiado, especialemtne con el manejo de las variables `validar` y `correcto`. Siguiendo tu idea inicial puedes hacer algo como:

```
def verificar_clave(passw):

    if not 6 <= len(passw) <= 12:
        return False

    numeros = 0
    mayusculas = 0
    minusculas = 0

    for carac in passw:
        if carac.isspace():
            return False
        elif carac.isdigit():
            numeros += 1
        elif carac.isupper():
            mayusculas += 1
        elif carac.islower():
            minusculas += 1

    return numeros >= 4 and mayusculas !=0 and minusculas >= 4
```

Recuerda usar `elif` siempre que sea posible. No tiene sentido comprobar por ejemplo si un carácter es una letra minúscula si previamente ya sabemos que es una letra mayúscula.

Dado que usas Python 2, si usas cadenas (`str`) la validación fallará si intentas validar cadenas con caracteres no ASCII (tildes, "ñ", etc):

```
>>> print verificar_clave('CAmión2016')
# False
```

Esto se resuelve simplemente pasando una cadena unicode:

```
>>> print verificar_clave(u'CAmión2016')
# True
```

No existe este problema en Python 3.